# use unix tools (e.g. sort) over field extracted from line-delimited JSON

Tags: json, unix, twitter, jq

A tool like [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) turns out to be extremely useful for declaratively extracting and filtering content from [line-delimited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Delimited_JSON). However, it appears to require slurping all objects into memory to perform operations such as sorting, and generally it may be useful to exploit existing *NIX tools to process one or more fields from the JSON *while retaining the original JSON blobs alongside*.

For example, given a line-delimited JSON from the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview), I'd like to sort the tweet JSON blobs by timestamp. This can be achieved by converting the Twitter date format to [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (for which lexicographic and chronological ordering are identical), prepending the JSON tweet blob with that date, passing the stream through GNU `sort`, and `cut`ting to remove the prepended date.

While it is possible to use `mkfifo` and `paste` to achieve this, I hoped for a solution that was more concise by utilising `jq`.

Answer (score 3):

One can sort a stream of Twitter JSON blobs with:

```
jq -r '(.created_at | strptime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y") | todate) + "\t" + tostring' |
sort -k1,1 |
cut -f2
```

For each JSON blob, the `jq` command parses the "created_at" field and outputs an ISO8601 date, followed by a tab, followed by the original JSON (which does not contain tabs or newlines). The `--raw-output`/`-r` flag ensures this is not JSON-encoded, but output as raw text. The stream is then sorted by GNU `sort` or equivalent, and the JSON blobs alone are retuned by `cut`.

Comment: It turns out the string formatting shorthand `jq -r '"\(.created_at | strptime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y") | todate)\t\(.)"'` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that jq can easily be used with other command-line tools is indeed one of jq's strengths, but it is no longer necessary to use the "slurp" option (--slurp or -s) to accomplish tasks such as the one described (i.e., to reduce an input stream of JSON entities).  The key is the new "inputs" filter in jq version 1.5.

To illustrate how "inputs" can be used to avoid having to read the input file into memory, consider the task of finding the maximum value of a file of JSON entities.  Here is one solution:

```
$ jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i (null; [., $i] | max)'
```

Notice that the -n option is required here.

In summary, with jq 1.5, one can easily process a stream of JSON entities (such as might be contained in a file) by reading in one at a time, whether or not each input entity is on a line by itself.  The key is to use "inputs" and the "-n" option.

Similarly, very large text files can now also be handled on a line-at-a-time basis while still being able to perform some reduction operations; this would be done using the -R option together with -n and *inputs*.

Comment: But piping or slurping would still be necessary to achieve a global reordering function (e.g. sorting a file of JSONs).

Comment: Nope.  Try this with a stream of JSON blobs as input: jq -n '[inputs] | sort'

Comment: p.s. Of course, writing [inputs] would cause the entire input to be read into memory, but in practice, one is more likely to write something like [inputs | filter], in which case only the array of filtered inputs would be retained in memory.

Comment: But is `jq -n '[inputs] | sort` not effectively slurping? Its memory usage seems to suggest so!